# How to call mock method instead of real method in mockito/Junit

Tags: unit-testing, testing, junit, automation, mockito

I want to call `ClassA.mockMethod()` whenever `objOfClassB.realMethod()` method is invoked.

```
public class ClassA{
     public static int mockMethod(String url, MySql sql){
        int res=0
        // do work
        return ;
    }

}

Definition of executeUpdate1()
class Veps{
    protected synchronized int realMethod(String url, MySql sql){
    ----
    -----
    }
}

public class VepsTest {
        public void setUp() throws Exception {

            veps = mock(Veps.class);

            when(objOfClassA.realMethod(any(String.class), any())).thenReturn(objOfClassB.mockMethod(any(String.class),any()));
         }
}


org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
2 matchers expected, 4 recorded.
This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
    //incorrect:
    someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
    //correct:
    someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the mockito reports the errors clearly:

> Invalid use of argument matchers! 2 matchers expected, 4 recorded.

you shouldn't using `Matcher`s in any `then*` clause. your problem can be fixed as:

```
when(veps.executeQuery1(any(String.class), any(MySql.class)))
     .thenReturn(DBConnection.mockExecuteQuery("??","??"));

when(veps.executeUpdate1(any(String.class), any()))
     .thenReturn(DBConnection.mockExecuteUpdate("??","??"));
```

but another problem appears: **why did you need query the result from the database?** you can simply take a constant value to fake the result:

```
when(veps.executeQuery1(any(String.class), any(MySql.class)))
     .thenReturn(1);
//               ^--- replace the constant 1 with yours

when(veps.executeUpdate1(any(String.class), any()))
     .thenReturn(1);
//               ^--- replace the constant 1 with yours
```

you need to see [mockito documentation](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki) as further before using it in your test.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I replaced any() with "??" and the IDE gives the compilation warning

--- "The method mockExecuteQuery(String, MySql) in the type DBConnection is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)"

I need to implement the mock methods instead of faking the answer since my testing relies on the data which gets inserted and pulled.. I need to mock the database, but preserve the behaviour of a real database

Comment: @SharatChandra Not at all. but I still ask you: "**why did you need query the result from the database?**"

Comment: The code does certain operations on database. My test has to validate whether the correct data got written into the database, without using an actual database

Comment: @SharatChandra well, if you want to validate the data from database. why did you should mock it again? you should just assert the result as your expected via `assertThat(...)`  or `assertEquals(..., ...)`.

Comment: Now that I have changed the names of the method and made it a non-database questiona,  how can we call the mock method instead of calling the real method ?

I really need to call a fake method instead of real method. 

I get the following compilation error in IDE when i reaplce any(), with "??"
The method mockExecuteUpdate(String, MySql) in the type DBConnection is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)

Comment: @SharatChandra the code above I typed `"??"` which means I don't know what the actually parameter you want to pass. it is a placeholder.